# DataContractJsonSerializer stringifies DateTime values inside dictionaries during deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json-deserialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I need a JSON serializer/deserializer that comes with .NET. I **cannot** use Newtonsoft Json.NET.

As far as I know, that leaves me with **JavaScriptSerializer** and **DataContractJsonSerializer**. JavaScriptSerializer didn't work properly, because it insists on some silly format for datetimes, which loses the UTC offset after being deserialized, nevermind that.

I am using **DataContractJsonSerializer**, and the test method below shows what is wrong.
I am specififying custom date format (ISO) for both serialization and deserialization, and the string looks OK. Additionally, it is readable by the Json.NET correctly.

How can I efficiently and generically workaround this issue, *without doing any regexes and manual* conversions?

```
[Test]
    public void SerializerFailure()
    {
       TestObject testObject = new TestObject() {Dict = new Dictionary<string, object>() {{"DateTest", DateTime.UtcNow}, {"DecimalTest", 66.6M}}};
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<DateTime>(testObject.Dict["DateTest"]);

        string serialized = this.Serialize(testObject);
        //output is OK...

        //{"Dict":{"DateTest":"2019-01-07T23:16:59.5142225Z","DecimalTest":66.6}}
        TestObject deserialized = this.Deserialize<TestObject>(serialized);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<string>(deserialized.Dict["DateTest"]);

        TestObject newtonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObject>(serialized);
        testObject.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(newtonDeserialized); //passes OK


        testObject.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(deserialized); //Fails

        //ERROR: Expected member Dict[DateTest] to be 
        //      "2019-01-07T23:27:23.0758967Z" with a length of 28, but
        //      "07.01.2019 23:27:23" has a length of 19.
        //          Expected member Dict[DateTest] to be
        //      "2019-01-07T23:27:23.0758967Z", but
        //      "07.01.2019 23:27:23" differs near "07."(index 0).

    }
```

Serialization:

```
    public string Serialize(object objectToPost)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings() { DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("O"), UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true };

            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer
                = new DataContractJsonSerializer(objectToPost.GetType(), settings);
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, objectToPost);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Deserialization

```
    public T Deserialize<T>(string stringContent)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringContent)))
            {
                var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings() { DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("O"), UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true };
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), settings);
                return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Error while deserializing string as {typeof(T).Name}", ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary with untyped `object` values?  The data contract [known type mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types) works by inserting a `"__type"` property, and so only works for data contract types that map to a JSON object.  And, unlike Json.NET (see [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) for details), the data contract serializer has no built-in date recognition engine.

Comment: So, since JSON itself has no date/time primitive, `DateTime` values stored in untyped properties will roundtrip as strings.

Comment: @dbc - because this is a framework code which should accept arbitrary data from the user - dictionary might contain strings, integers, booleans and other primitives. All works OK except for those damn dates :)